# When react renders a component does it always render on the non-virtual DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a console.log in a render method of a component:

```
class MyComp extends React{
    render(){
      console.log('rendering')
      return <div>Hello</div>
    }
}
```

Whenever this component renders I'll see it in the console. Does that always mean that the Virtual Dom is re-rendering?

Put another way, is logging the render method a good way to know if the non-virtual DOM is re-rendering?

Comment: console.log is a way to know that *virtual* DOM is rerendering. The purpose of virtual DOM is to limit changes in real DOM.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever this component renders I'll see it in the console. Does that
>   always mean that the Virtual Dom is re-rendering?

Yes, you are right, Virtual Dom is re-rendering.

> Put another way, is logging the render method a good way to know if
>   the non-virtual DOM is re-rendering?

Putting console to render method is good and simple way to know when your component is updating.

---

There are 3 cases (as i know) when react component is re-rendering

1. New props
2. New state
3. component.forceUpdate() method (never used it)

You can read more [here](https://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/).